# Hide specific part of passed parameters in URL

Tags: javascript, php, parameters, get, hide

I am passing multiple parameters in select form with GET method. I want to hide 3 from 4 parameters in URL after form submit. I have an options with 4 values and the I explode them and get each like that:

```
<select name="hardware">
<option value="Bitmain AntMiner S9|1-btc-sha-256|14000|1375">BITMAIN AntMiner S9</option>
<option value="Bitmain AntMiner D3|34-dash-x11|15000|1200">BITMAIN AntMiner D3</option>
</select>

<?php 
$hardware = $_GET["hardware"];
$hardware_explode = explode('|', $hardware);
echo $hardware_explode[0];
echo $hardware_explode[1];
echo $hardware_explode[2];
echo $hardware_explode[3];
?>
```

in URL it is like that: `example.com/calculate.php?hardware=Bitmain+AntMiner+S9%7C1-btc-sha-256%7C13000%7C1375`

and I want it to be `example.com/calculate.php?hardware=Bitmain+AntMiner+S9`

How can I hide this last 3 parameters in JS or PHP?

Comment: use `POST` and not `GET`, you can't hide selectively

Comment: It might help if we knew *why* - What do you want to do with them at the other end and why do you want them hidden?

Comment: This is definitely an http://xyproblem.info/ Using `GET` means you can bookmark the result. If that isn't necessary, use `POST`. If you want the result to be bookmarkable, replace the actual info with an id, like Quentin suggested, and determine the hash data in the backend.

Comment: @Chakachuk Since it wasn't suggested yet, you can redirect to the other URL using `header("Location: calclate.php?hardware=...");`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want them to be submitted, don't put them in the form in the first place.

```
<option value="Bitmain AntMiner S9">
```

Comment: I need them to be passed but I do not want them to be visible in URL

Comment: @Chakachuk — You can't really do that. Consider making the names unique (or just using IDs) and looking up the rest of the information in a database.

Comment: What if I will make in that way? If accessed URL is example.com/calculate.php?hardware=Bitmain+AntMiner+S9 than call POST request to this option <option value="Bitmain AntMiner S9|1-btc-sha-256|14000|1375">

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way to do it from client side and to hide the query parameters like 1hidden and 1 showing. But you can completely avoid sending values in query parameter by using "POST" method.